# Initialize UWP Radio Button Group

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have 2 UWP RadioButtons bound to a boolean on the ViewModel. When I initialize OptionOn to true in the ViewModel the button appears as unchecked and OptionOff is checked. My code is adapted from Jerry Nixon's [Data binding to a Radio Button in XAML](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/12/lets-code-data-binding-to-radio-button.html)

The XAML:

```
<RadioButton 
    GroupName="grpOptions" 
    Content="Option On" 
    IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.OptionOn,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<RadioButton 
    GroupName="grpOptions" 
    Content="Option Off" 
    IsChecked="{x:Bind ViewModel.OptionOff,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**Edit 1:** The ViewModel inherits from `Template 10 ViewModelBase`

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    bool _OptionOn = true
    public bool OptionOn { get { return _OptionOn; } set { Set(ref _OptionOn, value); } }

    public bool OptionOff { get { return _OptionOn; } set { Set(ref _OptionOn, false); } }
```

I also tried initializing OptionOn to true in the ViewModel ctor with the same incorrect outcome. How do I initialize OptionOn to true in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_OptionOff` isn't being used at all, so remove it.

I don't know what base class your view model has, but I'm assuming your `Set` method has a `[CallerMemberName]` attribute on the third `propertyName` parameter. This will raise a property changed notification only for the specific property being set, but both properties will change (since they're sharing the same backing value). So you must raise property changed notifications for each property (as Jerry did in his article).

Also your `OptionOff` property is setting the value to `false` always, is this desired?

It seems like you actually want a checkbox here instead of two radio buttons.

Do you always want `OptionOff` to have the opposite value to `OptionOn`? If so, you will need the property to be:

```
public bool OptionOff { get { return !_OptionOn; } set { Set(ref _OptionOn, !value); } }
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Decade Moon. I have edited my question to show ViewModel inherits from Template 10 ViewModelBase which raises property changed notifications. I have also removed `_OptionOff`. Radio buttons are required in the spec to set a single boolean property. The question uses a simplified code sample. In reality the options (eg StandardPackage/LuxuryPackage) toggle a single boolean where a checkbox does not provide sufficient info to the user. Binding is working, selecting a button sets the property correctly. The problem is initialization in the ViewModel.

Comment: I added a bit more to my answer. Both of your properties return the same value. There's a few issues here.